# Mute a single contact on WhatsApp

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger

Basically I still want to receive the messages from a contact but on lesser priority. I don't want a notification to appear when this contact messages me.

It is possible to mute a group chat, *but not for single contact*. Or I haven't found it.

How to mute a single contact on WhatsApp?

Comment: *[Mischealle](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/139317/mischealle) suggests (lacking the rep to comment):* Can't you just go to the person's profile and tern the mute mode on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the conversation click the three dots in the top right > View Contact > scroll down and select Mute.

Or go to contacts, tap the profile picture on the left, click the "i" icon, to view the contact and scroll down and select mute.

Using WhatsApp 2.12.250 on Android 5.1.1 (Nexus 5).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mute a group conversation, 
Whatsapp -> Click conversation you want to mute -> top right theres the options menu (three dots) -> Mute.

In that menu, you can deselect the notification setting or mute the conversation for a period of time.

I don't think there is a mute for a single contact though.

Comment: You can [block](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/s40/21064391) someone though

Comment: Just like I thought , there is no mute for a single contact.

Comment: @huey I know "block" but you cannot receive messages from them anymore

Comment: @raychenon currently whatsapp doesn't have this functionality

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the Settings -> Notifications. When you go to section "Group notifications", there is an option to set the notification tone, vibrate or popup notification.

In my case, I've turned off the vibration and set tone to "no sound" and it's fine for me.